# Fancybox with size to viewport but also with maximum width

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use Fancybox2 (fancybox.net) on my website.
When the ligthbox is shown I want it to size according to the screen width of the browser, so it's good to view on both mobile and desktop.
However, on the desktop I want the box to have a maximum width of 500px.

I was looking for a `max-width` option, but I can't find on http://fancybox.net/api how to do this.

Comment: First, you have to make sure what version of fancybox you are using. Anything related to fancybox v1.x (v1.3.4 the latest) you can find it at http://fancybox.net/ On the other hand, anything related to fancybox v2.x (v2.1.5 so far) you can find it at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ **Notice** that API options for v1.x and v2.x are incompatible with each other. Yes, both versions were developed by the same author but v2.x is the evolution of v1.x. BTW `maxWidth` is an option for fancybox v2.x, [see more](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: you are adding the fancybox script after `// ]]>` and outside the `.ready()` method so it's set as commented out (therefore not working)... add it just after your `jPages()` method instead. See http://jsfiddle.net/bWa2v/

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But why is the horizontal scrollbar still there?

Comment: I guess because your image is not responsive. Try adding a css rule like `max-width: 100%` so it can adjust to the width of the parent container `.testimonialcontainer .fulltext .img`

Comment: So I will post my comments as answer and it would be great if you can accept it then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything related to fancybox v1.x (v1.3.4 the latest) you can find it at [fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/). On the other hand, anything related to fancybox v2.x (v2.1.5 so far) you can find it at [fancyapps.com/fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

**Notice** that API options for v1.x and v2.x are incompatible with each other. BTW, `maxWidth` is an option for fancybox v2.x that doesn't exist in v1.x (therefore you won't find it at fancybox.net)

To avoid potential errors, set your fancybox initialization inside the `.ready()` method as in your [code](http://www.taj.nl/testimonials/) like :

```
// <![CDATA[
/* when document is ready */
$(function () { /* initiate the plugin */
    $("div.holder").jPages({
        containerID: "itemContainer",
        perPage: 4,
        startPage: 1,
        previous: "Vorige",
        next: "Volgende",
        startRange: 1,
        midRange: 5,
        endRange: 1
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth: 500,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextSpeed: 0,
        prevSpeed: 0,
        preload: 3,
        padding: 15
    });
});
// ]]>
```